# Exibir mensagem de sucesso uma única vez em laço for

Tags: php, html, for

Tenho o código:

```html
 for ($i=0; $i < count($descricao); $i++) {

   $id_caixa_hoje = $linha['id_caixa_hoje'];  
   $valor_formatado[$i] = abs($valor[$i]);  

   

   $inserir = mysql_query("INSERT INTO caixa_valores_extras (id_caixa, valor, descricao, funcionario) VALUES ('$id_caixa_hoje', '$valor_formatado[$i]', '$descricao[$i]', '$id_sessao')") or die("Erro: ".mysql_error());

       if($inserir == true){

        echo "<script>alert('Informações gravadas com sucesso');</script><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
       
       } else {

        echo "<script>alert('Erro. Falha ao gravar as Informações:');</script><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";

       } // Esta chave fecha o  if($inserir == true){

        } // Esta chave fecha o laço for
```

Por exemplo, se em meu formulário eu repetir um determinado dado 3 vezes,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

invés do php exibir a mensagem de sucesso apenas uma vez, ele exibe as três vezes.

Como posso fazer com que seja exibida uma única mensagem de sucesso ao fim do processo dos três INSERT's.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZHZMyi)

```
if ($i==(count($descricao)-1)){
   echo "<script>alert('Informações gravadas com sucesso');</script><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que criar uma variável de controle (auxiliar), para ficar dentro do laço, e o IF que exibe a mensagem de sucesso deve sair do laço.

Answer (score 0):

funciona tmb!

```html
for ($i=0; $i < count($descricao); $i++) {

   $id_caixa_hoje = $linha['id_caixa_hoje'];  
   $valor_formatado[$i] = abs($valor[$i]);  

   

   $inserir = mysql_query("INSERT INTO caixa_valores_extras (id_caixa, valor, descricao, funcionario) VALUES ('$id_caixa_hoje', '$valor_formatado[$i]', '$descricao[$i]', '$id_sessao')") or die("Erro: ".mysql_error());

       if($inserir == true){

        $t =1;
       
       } else {

        $t=0;

       } // Esta chave fecha o  if($inserir == true){

        } // Esta chave fecha o laço for        
        if($t==1){
echo "<script>alert('Informações gravadas com sucesso');</script><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}
else {
echo "<script>alert('Erro. Falha ao gravar as Informações:');</script><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}
```